# Trouble linking email to contact form using HTML

Tags: html, forms, email

I can't seem to figure out why the contents of the form will not send to my yahoo email. Any help would be most greatly appreciated. I am new to coing so this could be a very simple error.

```
<div class="bl-content">
                    <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                    <div id="form-main">
<div id="form-div">
<form class="form" id="form1">
  <form action="MAILTO:concroteau143@yahoo.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name"/>
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  </p>


  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
    </form>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

[`mailto:` does not work effectively as a form action](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). Use an HTTP(S) URI and a server side form handler  (either one written in a programming language of your choice that is supported by your server, or a third party hosted service) instead.

Additionally, your HTML is invalid. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org); `<form>` elements may not be nested. I can't remember how browsers attempt to recover from that particular error, but it is possible you are submitting your outer form and the form with an explicit action.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to include the sender email as mailto will launch default email program in client side to send the e-mail and that foces user to login to their mail account.
Fields for subject and body of the message should be named "Subject" and "Body" respectively.